# Static Street View image API Vs getTileUrl with google.maps.StreetViewTileData object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to combine 2,or more, street view static panorama images together for a wider panoramic view than would normally be supported by one image request.  I can do this using the static street view API however the resultant joined panoramic image is very angular at the join - eg:

[image]
[image]

Ideally I want to retrieve the tiles that make up a street view panoram as the curvature in the image is what I'd like to use

the v3 google maps API documentation for the use of gettileUrl only seems to relate to a custom panorma however the documentation isn't clear if it is possible to retrieve the google street view tiles

is it possible to review a google street view panorama ( not a custom panorama ) tile using
getTileUrl(pano:string, tileZoom:number, tileX:number, tileY:number)

I can get the pano:string using panorama.getPano() and use that to build my own gettileURL function that uses the undocumented URL cbk3.google.com/cbk?output=tile&panoid= - eg:

[image]
[image]

however I can not find any supported documentation so I assume it doesn't comply with the terms and conditions and isn't supported and therefore can not be used.

does the API support this with the street view image panorama tile- if not can this be a feature request.

Answer (score 3):

[From the TOS 10.1.3(a):](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

*You must not ... stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation;*

I would say your assumption is correct, you're not allowed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but google doesn't want you do to do it. [This article](http://www.newtonscannon.com/2014/01/26/capturing-spherical-scenes-from-google-streetview/) explains how to get the url for each tile. You can then download each tile and stitch them together into a single image. It follows a simple grid so there is no need to do advanced image processing.

**Note: by doing this you will be breaking Google's terms of service**